# Absolutely positioned parallax elements cause page height to be too large

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

EDIT: Here is another fiddle, this one showing the problem exactly as it is occurring.  In my eyes, since the section `bg` is INSIDE of the `container`, overflow hidden should be hiding it: http://jsfiddle.net/9SPDq/2/

I've implemented a custom parallax scrolling solution for my client's site.  I've included relevant snippets at the bottom of the question.  Since the site is a complete Ajax piece, the background must be as high as the highest page, which in this case is the homepage.  When looking at the homepage, all works as expected because all the pieces are arranged to fit a page of that height.  But when the user navigates to another page which is significantly shorter, the problem arises: the user can scroll 10x the height of the page because the `<html>` thinks it has to scroll to the parallax pieces, when in fact I only want it scrolling to the contents of `<body_container>`.  I have tried various combinations of `overflow:scroll` and `:hidden`, to no avail.

Here is a js fiddle of what I imagine SHOULD happen, but it seems that because in that example what is `#parent` is `<html>` in the production site and the `#container` is `<body>`, something is breaking.  Namely, because the way I've done it `#parent` requires `overflow:hidden`, it removes all scroll bars in the production site because I'm making `<html>` have `overflow:hidden`.

http://jsfiddle.net/vb5cp/

The blue `<section>`, in my eyes, is happily absolutely positioned outside of the scroll area, and for that reason should not affect the height of the `#container`.

Since the production site's beta is up, I'll provide a link to one of the pages exhibiting the problem, too, in case my descriptions haven't been clear: http://beta.firedogcreative.com/#motion_design

The question is: how do I retain the parallax background pieces, but control the height of my pages so that they only scroll to the height of the page contents?

To summarize the implementation:

```
<body>
    //here are the parallax pieces, with various hooks for the js that control them
    <section id="bckgrnd1"></section>
    <section id="bckgrnd2" data-type="background" data-speed="6"></section>
    <section id="bckgrnd3" data-type="background" data-speed="5"></section>

    <div id="body_container">
        //actual page content
    </div
</body>
```

Each piece has some simple css, the key part being the absolute positioning:

```
#bckgrnd2 {
    background: url(/media/images/parallax_pieces/smalltopFlame.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    height: 410px;
    width: 661px;
    margin-left: 215px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And finally the js that does all the work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("html").css("background-image","none");
    $("section").show();
    $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
        var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object 

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var yPos = -($(window).scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed')); 

            // Put together our final background position
            var coords = yPos + 'px';

            // Move the background
            $bgobj.css({ top: coords });
        }); 
    });    
});

// Create HTML5 elements for IE

document.createElement("article");
document.createElement("section");
```

Comment: This is too much information. I'd go with your simplified JSFiddle and try to fix an issue there.

Comment: But the problem is that I can't figure out why, in the simple fiddle, the absolutely positioned element DOESN'T cause the container to expand, where in my production site it does.  I think it has something to do with the fact that my container is `<body>`, but I'm not sure so I'm giving all the info someone might need to be able to figure it out.

Comment: My comment was aimed at getting you some better help. This question isn't getting any play most likely because what's being asked is a bit convoluted and the situation put before everyone is too complex. I'd simplify your question a lot, something akin to what you just wrote in your comment response to me. Then once you figure out something, if you still need help, start another question. That format really works well here at S.O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those who could follow my meandering and convoluted question, and who are having a similar problem, here is what was going on.

The `<sections>`, since they were being used as background image containers for a parallax scroll, were absolutely positioned and thus outside the flow.  Since their container was `<body>`, they were treated as a part of the page, and thus even though `overflow:hidden` was set on `<body>`, they weren't being viewed as overflow and thus the user could scroll too far down the page.  The solution was to contain all the `<section>`'s in a single div, and then set the height of THAT div in ADDITION to `<body>`.  The result is exactly what you would expect: the user can only scroll down as far as the set height, exactly as you would want.